# My prefix is the result of human creativity

Tags: riddle, word, language

My prefix is the result of human creativity.

My suffix creates hazards.

My infix represents me in another language.

I am often found in the ground.

What am I?

Comment: This doesn't appear to have a line relating the meaning of the entire word. Doesn't that make it a bit open-ended or (at the very least) vague?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Is it-

> Artichoke

prefix-

> Art, result of human creativity

Suffix-

> choke, choking is a hazard.

infix-

> ich, meaning I in German, representing me in a another language, thanks to @riley for this

Comment: You're very close!

Comment: I think the infix is rot13(vpu, yvgrenyyl "V" va Trezna), so it represents me.